# Ajax complete function issue

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on my collage project (Web app written in C#) and I'm using javascript
to dynamically add hotels with details and image using following code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'WebServiceBooking.asmx/Hotels',
    data: "{'stars':'" + stars + "','countryid':'" + country + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $('.hotels').empty();
        var hotels = data.d; //getting List<Hotel> from [WebMethod](works)
        window.t = "";
        window.ImageID = "";
        $.each(hotels, function (index, hotel) {
            $.ajax({ //this ajax is getting Image for specified hotel.HotelID
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'WebServiceBooking.asmx/HotelImage',
                data: "{'hotelid':'" + hotel.HotelID + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    window.ImageID = data.d;
                    //$('.hotels-image').attr('src', 'ImageHandlerFromID.ashx?ImageID=' + data.d);
                },
                complete: function (xhr, status) {
                    window.t += "<div class='hotel clearfix'><h3><a href='hotel.aspx?HotelID=" + hotel.HotelID + "'>" + hotel.HotelName + "</a></h3><p class='hotelAddress'>" + hotel.HotelAddress + "</p><p class='hotelPhone'>" + hotel.HotelPhone + "</p>";
                    window.t += "<img class='hotels-image' src='ImageHandlerFromID.ashx?ImageID=" + window.ImageID + "'/>";
                    window.t += "</div>";
                    console.log(window.ImageID);
                }
            });

            console.log(ImageID);
        });
        console.log(window.t);
    },
    complete: function (xhr, status) {
        $('.hotels').append(window.t);
    }
});
```

After several attempts, neither complete function works.

Comment: You forgot to explain what the problem is! What is the code supposed to do? What's it actually doing? Do you see any errors?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You need to wait for it to finish.

Comment: Ajax is async. The `complete` callback for the outer ajax call executes before the `complete` callbacks for the inner ajax calls.

Comment: @bfavaretto no errors shown in console, it reports all values right it just doesnt append in $('.hotels').append(window.t);

Comment: @JasonP how is that posible when inner Ajax is called before outer Ajax complete callback?

Comment: The inner callback is _specified_ before the outer callback executes, but are _executed_ after. Read [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) and try to understand the nature of async and when callbacks are actually executed.

Comment: thx for help...i solved it by adding async:false in inner one...

Comment: I strongly urge you to reconsider. That is the worst possible solution.

Comment: Do you control the app that provide the data? If so, why not have it send all of the necessary info about the hotels and prevent the need for all those extra (and most likely time consuming) AJAX calls?

Comment: @MasterAM yes i do and what is the best way to return 2 list<> items from webmethod then?

Answer (score 0):

The `complete` call will only complete the first ajax call. Not the one's in the for loop. If you want to check if all requests are done use `$.when`.

```
var requests = [];
var overall_data = {"hotels" = [], "hotel_images" = []}
var main_request = $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'WebServiceBooking.asmx/Hotels',
  data: "{'stars':'" + stars + "','countryid':'" + country + "'}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
    $('.hotels').empty();
    var hotels = data.d; //getting List<Hotel> from [WebMethod](works)
    overall_data["hotels"] = hotels
    window.t = "";
    window.ImageID = "";
    $.each(hotels, function (index, hotel) {
        var hotel_request = $.ajax({ //this ajax is getting Image for specified hotel.HotelID
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'WebServiceBooking.asmx/HotelImage',
            data: "{'hotelid':'" + hotel.HotelID + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                window.ImageID = data.d;
                overall_data["hotel_images"].push(data)
                //$('.hotels-image').attr('src', 'ImageHandlerFromID.ashx?ImageID=' + data.d);
            }
        });
        requests.push(hotel_request)
        console.log(ImageID);
    });
    console.log(window.t);
  }
});

requests.push(main_request);

$.when.apply(null, requests).done(function(){
// Do your stuff with overall_data
})
```